# Must be a block device or a regular file (ZFS, Solaris)

Tags: linux, solaris, zfs

I'm learning how to use ZFS on Solaris. I have 6 disks each with 8GB of storage (/export/home0-5). I want to put them all into one zfs pool. This is my setup.

```
# df -h
Filesystem             size   used  avail capacity  Mounted on
/dev/dsk/c0t0d0s0       11G   5.0G   5.7G    47%    /
/devices                 0K     0K     0K     0%    /devices
ctfs                     0K     0K     0K     0%    /system/contract
proc                     0K     0K     0K     0%    /proc
mnttab                   0K     0K     0K     0%    /etc/mnttab
swap                   1.3G   956K   1.3G     1%    /etc/svc/volatile
objfs                    0K     0K     0K     0%    /system/object
sharefs                  0K     0K     0K     0%    /etc/dts/sharetab
/usr/lib/libc/libc_hwcap1.so.1
                        11G   5.0G   5.7G    47%    /lib/libc.so.1
fd                       0K     0K     0K     0%    /dev/fd
swap                   1.3G    36K   1.3G     1%    /tmp
swap                   1.3G    28K   1.3G     1%    /var/run
/dev/dsk/c0t0d0s7      4.4G   4.5M   4.3G     1%    /export/home
/dev/dsk/c1tad0s7      7.9G   8.0M   7.8G     1%    /export/homeo
/dev/dsk/c1t1d0s7      7.9G   8.0M   7.8G     1%    /export/home1
/dev/dsk/c1t3d0s7      7.9G   8.0M   7.8G     1%    /export/home2
/dev/dsk/c1t0d0s7      7.9G   8.0M   7.8G     1%    /export/home3
/dev/dsk/c1t5d0s7      7.9G   8.0M   7.8G     1%    /export/home4
/dev/dsk/c1t2d0s7      7.9G   8.0M   7.8G     1%    /export/home5
```

When I run the zpool create command, I get this message.

```
cannot use '/export/home0': must be a block or regular file
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: What command exactly did you run?  Also please don't post images of text

Comment: Don't show image of text, as this makes it hard to read for example for blind people. Also show the command that caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your command should look like the following (to create a basic pool):

```
zpool create NAME c1t4d0s7 c1t1d0s7 ...
```

You need to use the disk names not their mount points.

Comment: It's usually advisable to use whole disks such as `c1t4do` in ZFS pools instead of using slices such as `c1t4d0s7`, but see https://serverfault.com/questions/628632/should-i-create-zfs-zpools-with-whole-disks-or-partitions for some reasons you might want to use slices.

Comment: It's also usually advisable not to create basic pools but it seems like OP is just learning in some sort of lab environment.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, the recommendations from Oracle for root pool is to use slices, nonroot is OK to use disks: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/819-5461/zfspools-4.html